# c++11 atomic ordering: extended total order memory_order_seq_cst for locks

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

from c++11 29.3-p3:

> There shall be a single total order S on all memory_order_seq_cst operations, consistent with the "happens before" order and modification orders for all affected locations, such that each memory_order_seq_cst operation B that loads a value from an atomic object M observes either one of the following values:
>
> -- the result of the last modification A of M that precedes B in S, if it exists, or
>
> -- if A exists, the result of some modification of M in the visible sequence of side effects with respect to B that is not memory_order_seq_cst and that does not happen before A, or
>
> -- if A does not exist, the result of some modification of M in the visible sequence of side effects with respect to B that is not memory_order_seq_cst.
>
> [ Note: Although it is not explicitly required that S include locks, it can always be extended to an order that does include lock and unlock operations, since the ordering between those is already included in the "happens before" ordering. --end note ]

In the last note, what does it mean by "always"?
I can understand that any certain implementation can be designed to support such an extended S. But in some general implementation that wasn't designed for it, I don't see that S can be extended with the described properties.

Does it mean an extended order that also satisfies the same visibility properties here?

I had sent this question to comp.std.c++ but got no answers there. http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_frm/thread/5242fa70d0594d1b#

Comment: please extend the question with relevant context...

Comment: I added citation for the whole paragraph 29.3-p3. What other context could I add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does it mean by "always"?

Always means that there exists a total order `S+l` on `seq_cst ops U lock ops` that is consistent with `happens-before` and `S`.

### Why is that

Fact 1: `S` is a total order consistent with `HB`.

Fact 2: Lock operations are ordered in the `HB` partial order, because they are acquire/release operations.

Fact 3: There are no cycles in `HB`.

Lemma 1: There are no cycles in `S' = S union HB`.

Proof: If there were any cycles in `S'`, they would be in the form `Aop1 <S Aop2 <HB Aop1`, because any two atomic operations are comparable in `S` and happens-before is transitive. That would contradict with Fact 1. QED

Conclusion: Because for each partial order (= without cycles) there exists its extension to total order (cf. topological sorting), there is a total order extending `S'`. So you just pick atomics and lock operations from it and get `S+l`.

> But in some general implementation that wasn't designed for it, I don't see that S can be extended so.

Such an implementation would not satisfy `mem_order_seq_cst` requirements.

Comment: It is generally true that you can extend any partial order to some total order (one or more), but the point here being that exists an extended S that has the properties described in the section (which I didn't cite all of it here). Also, I took it for granted that it does refer to all lock and unlock operations on all mutex objects.

Comment: I added the citation of the full section 29.3-p3. Why do you think that an extension of S' would satisfy the requirements of S?
What do you mean "mem_order_seq_cst requirements" that an implementation would or would not satisfy? I'm only talking about conforming implementations.

Comment: Suppose for example that an implementation uses OS support for the atomic and fences operation. This is enough for S as required. But then implements std::mutex using the atomics, and specifically using memory_order_release, for the unlock operation (rather than seq_cst). It would be conforming, but still I think it's quite obvious that the unlocks will not generally have a total order. On the other hand, by implementing unlock using seq_cst, it could design for extending S.

Comment: @itaj: "OS support for the atomic and fences operation. This is enough for S as required." I don't think so, at least I don't know such an OS. I may throw in an example where seq_cst is important if that'll help this discussion to be more clear.

Comment: @itaj: Requirements of S are fulfilled trivially: (1) Consistency with the modification orders is preserved by doing the extension, and (2) if the read operations read some values dependent on S, why should they read something else if you add opperations *other than atomics* to S?

Comment: So check me that you are saying that whether or not S had been defined to include locks and unlocks, it would impose equivalent requirements (for ordering, reads, visibility and anything relevant). And that this note only goes to explain why it is so.

Comment: @itaj: Basically, yes, that's how I feel it. It seems to me it even implies that seq_cst operations need behave as if each access was protected by a per-variable lock... seems like something to think about.

Comment: ok. These are quite a few interesting points, I'll have to think about it more to organize it. I pretty much assumed that the note being there only meant that the extended definition is supposed to actually make a difference. thanks.

Comment: only now I got around to complete that line of thought. So I basically understand and agree with all that, except for one fixable detail. HB is not transitive itself because consume doesn't necessarily happen before an operation that is sequenced after it. However, the standard requires HB to have no cycles, so as long as S is compatible with the transitive closure of HB, S is extendable to S'.